# Show a value depending on today's date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a "Calendar" table with days, and a text associated with each day (Turno A / Turno B)

[image]

I want to display the text associated with today's date on a card. In this case, December 6, it would be "TURNO A"

The expected output is something like this:

[image]

I am a newbie to Power BI / Dax. I tried to create a measure called "Currently working" with DAX, but couldn't. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try CALCULATE and SELECTEDVALUE functions. We filter Calendar by current date and return the value from 'Turno' column.

```
Currently working =
CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Calendar'[Turno] ), 'Calendar'[Dia] = TODAY () )
```